# Homogeneous second-order linear ODE with constant coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Okay, so how can you prove that $ = C_1 \cos  + C_2 \sin $ is the general solution of $'' + (^2)  = 0$, $ \neq 0$

Anyone willing to explain???

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What does "a2y" mean?

Comment: Hello, welcome to math.stackexchange. Please improve your question by explaining your thoughts on the problem, and/or showing the work you have done. Also consider taking a more descriptive title.

Comment: @Timbuc I edited

Comment: @Pedro Sorry I'm so lost, i need some explanation :(

Comment: That these functions are solutions is a simple question of checking them. That they are a general solution (that is, there are no others) is more a matter of analysis than of linear algebra. After all if one takes the same equations on a domain with multiple connected components, there will be other solutions. Hence I have re-tagged the question, removing `vector-spaces` and adding `real-analysis`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll sketch the uniqueness:

Note first that, as it is a *linear* differential equation, its solutions are a vector space $S$ over $\mathbf R$ (this means any linear combination of solutions is egain a solution.

Next, you can map $S$ into $\mathbf R^2$ by mapping a solution $y$ to $(y(0),y'(0)$ (the *initial conditions*). This map is clearly linear.To prove the uniqueness, all we have to do is to prove it is an *isomorphism*, i.e; it is both injective and surjective. We'll denote it $\varphi$.

Indeed, if it is bijective, suppose you have a solution $y\,$; you can find a solution $C_1 \cos ax+C_2\sin ax$ that satisfies the same initial conditions as $y(x)$ for some coefficients $C_1, C_2$ by solving a linear system of equations (this also prove the surjectivity of the mapping $y(x)\mapsto (y(0),y'(0))$. Hence by uniqueness,
$$y(x)=C_1 \cos ax+C_2\sin ax.$$

*Proof of injectivity*

As $\varphi$ is linear, it is enough to prove $\ker \varphi=\bigl\{0\bigr\}$. So let $y$ be a solution such that $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.

*Lemma.* For any solution of the equation $y''+a^2y=0$, the expression $a^2y^2+y'^2$ is constant.

Indeed let's differentiate: $$(a^2y^2+y'^2)'=2a^2yy'+2y'y''=2(a^2yy'+y'(-a^2y))=0.$$
By Rolle's theorem, $a^2y^2+y'^2$ is constant.
$$***$$

Let's apply this lemma to the present situation: we have
$$a^2y(x)^2+y'(x)^2=a^2y(0)^2+y'(0)^2=0.$$
A sum of squares can be zero only if each square is zero. Hence $y(x)=y'(x)=0$.

Comment: You misplaced a closing parenthesis in the equation before "Rolle's theorem".

Comment: Ot  I forgot to remove a spurious $2$ :o) Thank you for pointing the typo!

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier than you think.

First, if you let $ = C_1 \cos ax + C_2 \sin ax$, does this function solve the differential equation $y'' + a^2y = 0$? To show that it does, you need to differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$ twice, and plug the result into the differential equation instead of $y''$. Also, plug the expression for $y$ into the equation at the place, where it says "$y$". When doing this, do you get $0$? If you do, you have shown that $y$ solves the equation.

Also, how do you differentiate $y$ twice? You need to do both terms of $y$, but if you take for instance the first term $C_1\cos ax$, then this term differentiated once becomes $-aC_1\sin ax$ (you need to differentiate it again, of course).

Now, if you show that $y$ solves the equation, then there's this result called "uniqueness of solutions" that says that there can be no more solutions to the differential equations! This means that $y$ is the general solution.

The reason for this is that you have two arbitrary constants $C_1$, and $C_2$ in the expression for $y$, and your equation has order $2$.

I hope this helps.